# Return Json to an ajax success from an mvc contoller

Tags: json, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am sending Json to an mvc method and checking it against a schema for the correct key/value pairs.  If it passes, i want to send the user to abnother view on the same controller but if the Json fails, I want to display the missing key/value pairs in a modal dialog.  From some reason when I return the Json, it doesn't come accross to the view and I can't figure out why.  Here's my code:

Model:

```
    public class EditReportResponseJon
{
    public string ErrorPath { get; set; }
    public string ErrorKind { get; set; }
    public Boolean Success { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
            [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult SubmitReport(string JsonStringSend)
        {
            dynamic JSend = JObject.Parse(JsonStringSend);
            var schema = JsonSchema4.FromType<ReportItem>();
            var schemaData = schema.ToJson();
            var errors = schema.Validate(JSend.JsonString);
            schema = JsonSchema4.FromJson(schemaData);


            if (errors.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (var error in errors)
                    Console.WriteLine(error.Path + ": " + error.Kind);

                List<EditReportResponseJon> JsonResults = new List<EditReportResponseJon>{
                    new EditReportResponseJon{Success = false, ErrorKind = "The error", ErrorPath = "The path of the error"}
                };
                return Json(JsonResults, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
            else
            {

                List<EditReportResponseJon> JsonResults = new List<EditReportResponseJon>{
                    new EditReportResponseJon{Success = false, ErrorKind = "", ErrorPath = ""}
                };
                return Json(JsonResults, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
        }
```

And my view:

```
    $('#SubmitReport').on("click", function () {
    editor.session.getUndoManager().markClean();
    //buttonpressed = true;
    //window.onbeforeunload=null;
    //Hide the error messages if they are showing.
    $('#ReportNameError').css('visibility', 'hidden');
    $('#DocumentMsg').css('visibility', 'hidden');
    var EditorsValue = jQuery.parseJSON(editor.getValue());
    var UserReportFilename = $('#JsonFilename').val();
    var JsonStringSend = JSON.stringify({ JsonString: EditorsValue, UserReportFilename: UserReportFilename });

    //Send the Json to the server
    $.ajax({
        url: "@Url.Action("SubmitReport", "Reporting", null)",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        data: { 'JsonStringSend': JsonStringSend },
        success: function (JsonResults, status) {
            console.log(JsonResults);
            if (JsonResults.Success === true){
        //Redirect user to the Report Queue if success
            @*var link = '@Url.Action("ReportManagement", "Reporting", null)';
        window.location.href = link;*@
            console.log('success!')
        }
            if (JsonResults.Success === false) {
                console.log('Unsuccessful!')
            //show error div with errors.
        }
                },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log(textStatus + ": " + errorThrown + "." + "  Please see above if applicable");
    }
});
});
```

The `console.log(JsonResults);` displays [object, object].  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Change your return type to JsonResult instead of ActionResult.

Comment: I still get `[object Object]` returned when I use `JsonResult`.  This is really strange.

Comment: What are your expecting. You sending a collection (not sure why when it only contains one object) so you need `if (JsonResults[0].Success === true) {`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you Stephen, this was the answer:  `(JsonResults[0].Success === true) {`  Once implemented it worked.